# payment adaptive payment returnurl without transaction ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new to paypal API, now I am trying to integrate paypal adaptive payment with my website.

1. I created test business paypal account and user account in paypal sandbox.
2. I set auto reply and data transfer to be on.

Everything is working fine until paypal redirects to my return url but I dont get tx(Trasaction ID) as POST or GET data.

Anybody has any idea ? really appreciate for all suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With paypal adaptive payments api, the IPN will come with a paykey instead of a transaction id so use it in your code.

Here is real IPN formatted as JSON

```
{"payment_request_date":"Sun Jun 24 06:12:20 PDT 2012",
"return_url":"http://redacted/paypal/transactions/3?status=completed",
"fees_payer":"EACHRECEIVER",
"ipn_notification_url":"http://redacted/paypal/notifications",
"sender_email":"redacted",
"verify_sign":"AFcWxVredacted",
"test_ipn":"1",
"transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn":"redacted",
"transaction[0].receiver":"redacted",
"cancel_url":"http://redacted/paypal/transactions/3?status=canceled",
"transaction[0].is_primary_receiver":"false",
"pay_key":"AP-redacted",
"action_type":"PAY",
"transaction[0].id":"redacted",
"transaction[0].status":"Completed",
"transaction[0].paymentType":"SERVICE",
"transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn":"Completed",
"transaction[0].pending_reason":"NONE",
"transaction_type":"Adaptive Payment PAY",
"transaction[0].amount":"USD 1.00",
"status":"COMPLETED",
"log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction":"false",
"charset":"windows-1252",
"notify_version":"UNVERSIONED",
"reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error":"true"}
```